# Ajax call to C# webservice returns object within an object?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I have the following C# webservice (for testing purposes), which I eventually will turn into a WCFWebservice.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class Albums : WebService {

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public Person GetPeople() {
        return new Person("Mike", 12);
    }
}
```

And I call this using the following js:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/webservice/Albums.asmx/GetPeople',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'post',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

But the weird thing (to me) is, I can't access `data.Name` within `success()`.
Somehow, it adds a object `d` to `data`.
So if I want to access the name, I need to use: `data.d.Name`.

Where does this `d` come from?

Comment: As far as I know, thats just the way it is. Look at this quesion if you want to change the behaviour. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811525/removing-the-d-object-from-asp-net-web-service-json-output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is nothing to worry about. It comes from using the  OData protocol on the server:

> This pattern ensures JSON payloads returned from OData services are
>   valid JSON statements, but not valid JavaScript statements. This
>   prevents an OData JSON response from being executed as the result of a
>   cross site scripting (XSS) attack.

To find out the nitty-gritty, see http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/json-format.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by default for both OData formatting and also as an security measure. You can easily remove this by adding the following to the ScriptMethod:

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
```