# How to change ASP.NET WebMethod's 'd' identifier in a JSON response, to a different name?

Tags: .net, jquery, ajax, json, webmethod

This works: through jQuery I'm using a [jQuery.ajax(..)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call to a page *e.g. Default.aspx/GetStatus* having a [WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) attribute:

```
// Default.aspx
[WebMethod()]
static public bool GetStatus(long id)
{ //...
```

The JSON response contains the correct boolean value in the format `{ d: true }`. However I don't understand the origin of the resulting "d" member name.
**Where does the "d" identifier come from (how is it decided) and how can I change its name?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What does .d in JSON mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830112/what-does-d-in-json-mean)

Comment: +1 That's awesome - I laughed at "well it had to be something". So that answers half the question, which I can live with. Do you have any idea how to change it?

Comment: Well, if you want to change it real bad, you could modify the rendered response with an HttpModule, as indicated here: http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Article/19901/0/page/3

Comment: Or you could wrap all your calls to the service with a JavaScript function that creates a new property. Neither of which sounds like a great idea.

Comment: found a [link](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/) with little explanatation for the .d Encapsulation