# Deserializing JSON from ASP.net web service into C# object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

After spending a day reading through posts here I still can't get this to work so hopefully this makes sense to someone here.

The web service returns this simple JSON

```
{"d":{"__type":"TestWebServices.Person","Name":"Bob","FavoriteColor":"Green","ID":0}}
```

Then I am using C# code to deserialize

```
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));
Person someone = (Person)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(responseStream);
```

When I use this model someone is created but all the properties are null

```
[DataContract]
public class Person {
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FavoriteColor { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

I tried being more literal and used this model

```
[DataContract]
public class Person {
    [DataMember]
    public PersonItem d { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class PersonItem {
    [DataMember]
    public string __Type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FavoriteColor { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

And got this error, which I don't even know where to start with

Element ':d' contains data from a type that maps to the name ':GEMiniWebServices.Person'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to 'TestWebServices.Person' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: If you add a `Service Reference`, the generated client will deserialize the response for you.

Answer (score 1):

__Type should never be part of your object. It's a hint to the serializer. Also, the type hint that you have in your JSON object is bad. [Stand-Alone JSON Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx) says:

> To preserve type identity, when serializing complex types to JSON a
>   "type hint" can be added, and the deserializer recognizes the hint and
>   acts appropriately. The "type hint" is a JSON key/value pair with the
>   key name of "__type" (two underscores followed by the word "type").
>   The value is a JSON string of the form
>   "DataContractName:DataContractNamespace" (anything up to the first
>   colon is the name).
>
> The type hint is very similar to the xsi:type attribute defined by the
>   XML Schema Instance standard and used when serializing/deserializing
>   XML.
>
> Data members called "__type" are forbidden due to potential conflict
>   with the type hint.

It works with the following if you rewrite the `__type` declaration as `Person:#TestWebServices` or eliminate it:

```
namespace TestWebServices
{
    [KnownType(typeof(Person))]
    [DataContract]
    public class PersonWrapper
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Person d { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string FavoriteColor { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info JamieSee.
I had also tried it without the "__type" and got the same error.
The web service is creating that type hint, not sure what I can do about that.

Comment: Added comment - If I strip out the "d":{"__type":"GEMiniWebServices.Person" from the JSON Both the DataContractJsonSerializer and JavaScriptSerializer have no problem parsing the data into the PersonItem object

So is the purpose of "d":{"__type":"?  It's obviously making something simple complicated.

Thoughts?

Comment: This issue is described here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72443/Deserializing-Microsoft-Ajax-ClientScript-JSON-in  The article suggests stripping out the json that is causing the issue.

Comment: It works if you rewrite the `__type` declaration to `Person:#TestWebServices` or eliminate it.

Comment: Here's [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588589/why-do-asp-net-json-web-services-return-the-result-in-d) related to the "purpose" of "d" : {.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding (and I'm kind of taking a bit of a stab here so the exact namespace my be incorrect)

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestWebServices.Person")]
```

to your DataContractAttribute on Person.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestWebServices.Person")]
public class Person {
    [DataMember]
    public PersonItem d { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class PersonItem {
    [DataMember]
    public string __Type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FavoriteColor { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```