# How to parse this JSON in android (returned from .NET webservice)

Tags: java, android, asp.net, json

I have ASP.NET webservice which return Person object in JSON format. Please see following Webservice code:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public Person person() {

    Person me = new Person();
    me.name = "Mark";
    me.lastname = "Brawn";

    return me;
}


public class Person {

 public String name;
 public String lastname;
}
```

Then I tried to parse this response in Android client and I get following JSON Output:

```
{
"d": {
    "__type": "WebService+Person",
    "name": "Mark",
    "lastname": "Brawn"
}
```

}

This output seems valid JSON format, but I would like to know how to properly get properties from this output ( name, lastname...).

In android I parsed this output:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
json.getString("name");
```

But I get an exception:

```
07-12 19:07:14.708: W/System.err(21575): org.json.JSONException: No value for name
```

**So actually i would like to get value "name", and "lastname" from this JSON. Any help appriciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON Object being created by "`result`" is likely the parent `JSON` object, while `"name"` is in the nested JSON object. Try `json.getObject("d").getString("name")`.

Comment: Actually it works :). But I'm confused. Why is ASP.NET webservice returning this kind of JSON? Why not only "name" and "surname" properties?

Comment: Not sure, that's a question for the developer who created the ASP.NET web service. Please accept the answer in addition to your upvote.

Comment: Strange. Because I saw a lot of sample code regarding parsing JSON in android, but I never saw an output like mine ( and solution like yours ). But ok , at least it works. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, the "d" is apparently a security feature in ASP.Net: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588589/why-do-asp-net-json-web-services-return-the-result-in-d

Answer (score 0):

you can use the GSON easy to pares json data

[gson download](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)