# Ajax cannot read Serialized Json dictionary correctly

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, dictionary

This is what I have in my c# code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
.....
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
d.Add("id", id.ToString());
d.Add("type", "error");
d.Add("msg", pex.Message);
.....
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
```

My AJAX

```
......
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Service1.svc/MyCall",
                    data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,

                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#lblResult").html("loading");
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#lblResult").html(data['id']);
                    },
......
```

This is the response in Firebug

```
"{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"error\",\"msg\":\"An exception occurred during a Ping request.\"}"
```

This is the JSON in Firebug

```
0       "{"
1       """ 
2       "i"
3       "d"
4       """
5       ":"
6       """
7       "1"
8       """
9       ","
10      """
11      "t"
ETC
```

Problem: I cannot get data['id'] or any data['SOMETHING'].

How can I get it based on the response received?
Any other way to do all?

Comment: tried already but I get "error" in $("#lblResult").html(data['id']); - No details or nothing

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the JSON is not being converted back to a JavaScript object correctly.  Try this

```
success: function (data) { 
if (data.hasOwnProperty("d"))
            {
                var response = JSON.parse(data.d);
                $("#lblResult").html(response["id"]);
            }
            else
            {
                var response = JSON.parse(data);
                $("#lblResult").html(response["id"]);
            }
}
```

The .d is required as .Net adds this for security reasons, a better explanation than I can give can be found here [Why do ASP.NET JSON web services return the result in 'd'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588589/why-do-asp-net-json-web-services-return-the-result-in-d).

Then since the returned value is a JSON string, this needs to be parsed to become the Javascript Object

Comment: I get SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data -   var response = JSON.parse(data.d);

Comment: What do you get if you console.log data.d?

Comment: The ajax is in the aspx page

Comment: You can also check the data type of your ajax call, i.e. dataType: 'json', the data type here should be json not html

Comment: Could you please update the question with the full Ajax request, hopefully we'll be able to see what's wrong from there

Comment: I included the ajax request. hope it helps.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a check for d in the returned object, hopefully this will solve the issue