# Asp.net WebMethod - return string[] and parse it using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I need to return an array of string from MyMethod at codebehind. But do I parse it on aspx page using `javascript`?

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] MyMethod(){
   return new[] {"fdsf", "gfdgdfgf"};
}

..........
function myFunction() {
            $.ajax({ ......
                    success: function (msg) {
                                //how do I parse msg?
                                }
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you've tagged your class with `[ScriptService]` to allow it to be called through AJAX.  Something like:

```
[ScriptService] //<-- Important
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
   [ScriptMethod] //<-- WebMethod is fine here too
   public string[] MyMethod()
   {
      return new[] {"fdsf", "gfdgdfgf"};
   }
}
```

You can then read the result with [jQuery directly](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/), as there's no need to *parse* anything:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService.asmx/MyMethod",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      // msg.d will be your array with 2 strings
    }
  });
});
```

Another approach is to just include a reference to:

```
<script src="WebService.asmx/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This will generate proxy classes to allow you to call web methods directly.  For example:

```
WebService.MyMethod(onComplete, onError);
```

The `onComplete` function will receive a single parameter with the results of the web service call, in your case a Javascript array with 2 strings.  In my opinion, this is an easier solution than using jQuery and worrying about the URL and HTTP payload.

Comment: how do I parse msg using WebMethod?

Comment: @Grienders - Is your response in SOAP or JSON?  `[WebMethod]` supports both.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery iterator to iterate over the strings in the msg result like so.

```
function myFunction() {
    $.ajax({ ......
        success: function (msg) {
            $.each(msg, function(index, value) {
                alert(value);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The response `object` will contain an object called `d` which wraps the values returned from your WebMethod.  Just access it like so:

```
function myFunction() {
    $.ajax({ ......
        success: function (msg) {
            //how do I parse msg?
            alert(msg.d); //alerts "fdsf", "gfdgdfgf"
        }
    });
};
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/830112/1289454) for an explanation.