# errors in parsing json string as object

Tags: jquery, json

I tried some answers from stack overflow but it didn’t work form me...
am calling asmx web service in jquery
Here is the code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:4845/service.asmx/HelloWorld",
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: handleHtml,
                error: ajaxFailed
            });
        });
        function handleHtml(data, status) {

            debugger
            //var myObject = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                alert(data.d[1].date);
            }
        }
        function ajaxFailed(xmlRequest) {
            alert(xmlRequest.status + ' \n\r ' +
              xmlRequest.statusText + '\n\r' +
              xmlRequest.responseText);
        }
</script>
```

When am parsing its returning null and if i do with out parsing its shows unidentified object..
Here is my json string

```
   [{"name":"jef","date":"10/12/2012","ID":0,"description":"test1"},
    {"name":"sam","date":"18/12/2012","ID":0,"description":"test2"},
   {"name":"dan","date":"1/1/2013","ID":0,"description":"test3"},
    {"name":"san","date":"1/2/2013","ID":0,"description":"test4"}]
```

I want to know how to parse the data and display

Comment: Are you reaching the handleHtml handler, or the ajaxFailed handler.

Comment: what is `data.d`?  Maybe try `data[i].date`

Comment: i can reach handleHtml(data, status) when i put debugger there i can able to see the json string, but i cant parse  or alert(data.d[1].date); ...

Comment: wiery i tried that in for loop data.lenght im getting undefined and is if i directly write alert(data[0].name it throws (is null or not an object)

Comment: try putting 'data' in a console.debug statement and seeing what the browser is getting. (firebug or console in chrome)

Comment: Hi Pow-lan when i do console.debug(data); i got an error : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last i found the answer ..

```
    function handleHtml(data, status) {

        data = data.d
        var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            alert(data.[i].date);
        }
    }
```

we have to do data = data.d .. still i dont understand why i have to do data.d

[What does .d in JSON mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830112/what-does-d-in-json-mean)