# How do I send and receive a JSON POST between an iOS device to an ASP.NET URL?

Tags: asp.net, ios, json

I am working on an iDevice app that needs to share data with a windows server. I have looked at a number of examples on the web and come up with the implementation listed below. The iOS app sends the JSON to the web-server and receives a JSON response back. However, the response is not what I expect. I receive `{"d": "{\"name\": \"John Doe\", \"email\": \"test@gmail.com\"}"}` instead of `{\"name\": \"John Doe\", \"email\": \"test@gmail.com\"}` Any idea where the "d" is coming from?

iOS code:

```
-(void)checkWithServer {
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://texas/WebSite3/Service.asmx/doSomething"];
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"test@gmail.com", @"email",
                              @"John Doe", @"name",
                              nil];

    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&error];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: postURL
                                                           cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval: 60.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept"];
    [request setValue: @"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField: @"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: jsonData];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request
                                       queue: queue
                           completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if (error || !data) {
                                   // Handle the error
                               } else {
                                   // Handle the success
                               }
                           }
     ];
}
```

Web-server code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://texas/WebSite3")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment   the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public Service () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string doSomething(string email, string name)
    {
        return "{\"name\": \"" + name + "\", \"email\": \"" + email + "\"}";
    }
}
```

Apparently the web-server is smart enough to pull the JSON apart and assign the variables name and email.

Comment: Where the d is coming from? A google search brings back cool results!. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830112/what-does-d-in-json-mean

Comment: It never would have dawned on me that this could have been deliberate. :)