# How do I recieve JSON structures in a .NET web service

Tags: .net, json

I need to send a JSON structure from an iOS app to a .NET web service. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
   "Name":"Tom Jones",
   "Address":{
      "Street":"123 Some Ln.",
      "City":"Home Town",
      "State":"ZX",
      "Zip":12345
   },
   "Phone":"123-456-4567"
}
```

I know how to receive the Name and Phone values but I don't know what the Address should look like.
This is what I have for the Name and Phone:

```
public string doSomething(string name, string phone)
```

What should the Address input variable look like? Everything I have tried gives an error.

Comment: checke this URL : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/211489/Using-JSON-with-ASP-NET-3-5

Comment: Use Json.NET to parse the received structures :-)

Comment: I don't have an issue sending and receiving standard parameters like int, strings, etc. It is the structures that I am not sure how to deal with. .Net parses the JSON before I even see it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042506/how-do-i-send-and-receive-a-json-post-between-an-ios-device-to-an-asp-net-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried an object named Address with the nested values as properties?

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract]
public class Address
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Street {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string City {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string State {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public int Zip {get;set;}
}
```

so then the parameters in the method would look like:

```
public string doSomething(string name, Address address, string phone)
```

Comment: I had originally tried similar things. This is the response I get back: {"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""} Any other ideas?

Comment: By "tried similar things" do you mean this exact thing or even Vijay's similar solution?
Also, have you tried using attribute tags such as [DataContract] for the class and [DataMember] for the properties?

Comment: By "tried similar things" I meant in addition to trying your solution and the one of Vijay's. No, I have not tried [DataContract] for the class and [DataMember] for the properties. If you can point me to a sample that would be really helpful. Otherwise, I will search around. There seem to be many different ways to do thing and it is not clear which ones can be combined. Thanks for your help. In the process I discovered that I could generate JSON with the following statement: return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(user);

Comment: updated my answer to include attributes and reference required.
to be honest, I don't know if this will work as I am not in a position to test myself but I do know that this is the "appropriate" way to handle JSON.

Comment: That did not work either. Is there any way I can get a meaningful error message? I have no idea what it is objecting to.

Comment: Turns out the issue was that the variables in doSomething are case sensitive. The JSON had Name instead of name.

Comment: Turns out that the [DataMember] and [DataContract] are not required.

Comment: I didn't think so. Those attributes I've found to be required for XMl serialization. But coding is a fickle beast so thought it might work in your case. Glad you found the issue! I'll have to keep an eye out for the case sensitivity in the future myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly cast your JSON string to .Net class, Definition for class should be as below

```
public class Address
{
    public string Street {get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;}
    public string State {get;set;}
    public int Zip {get;set;}
}

public class User
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Address Address {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}
}

public string doSomething(User user)
```

Now you can directly access any member from `user` object.

Comment: I had originally tried similar things. This is the response I get back: {"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""} Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you check your request processing fiddler and any other tool?

Comment: Vijay, thanks for your help. I got fiddler up and running then found out it only looks on the PC running IIS. So I had to implement the client in JavaScript to see what was going on. It turns out it was just a matter of case sensitivity. To get your solution to work I would have to change the JSON to {"user": {...}}