# Can't remove .d encapsulation from JSON response in .net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

Even after the great blog post [Never worry about ASP.NET AJAX’s .d again](http://encosia.com/simplify-calling-asp-net-ajax-services-from-jquery/) I can't escape the .d encapsulation in my JSON response. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong so I'll copy both my serverside and clientside code.

I'm serializing JSON using Newtonsoft.JSON library.

Clientside:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#bt").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/MapView.aspx/GetLocations")%>",
            data: "{ type: '<%= Page.RouteData.Values["type"].ToString() %>', id: '<%= Page.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString() %>' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            dataFilter: function(data) {
                var msg;

                if (typeof (JSON) !== 'undefined' && 
                    typeof (JSON.parse) === 'function')
                    msg = JSON.parse(data);
                else
                    msg = eval('(' + data + ')');

                if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
                    return msg.d;
                else
                    return msg;
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Serverside

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetLocations(int id, string type)
    {
        string data = "";


        if (type == "attraction")
        {
            var attractions = db.Attraction
                                .Where(a => a.AttractionId == id)
                                .Select(p => new { p.AttractionId, p.Name, p.Description, p.Location })
                                .ToList();


            JObject attractionsJSON = new JObject(
                new JProperty("Attractions", new JArray(
                    from a in attractions
                    select new JObject(
                        new JProperty("id", a.AttractionId),
                        new JProperty("name", a.Name),
                        new JProperty("location", a.Location),
                        new JProperty("description", a.Description)
                        ))));

            data = attractionsJSON.ToString();
        }
        else if (type == "category")
        {
            var attractions = db.Attraction

                .Select(p => new { p.AttractionId, p.Name, p.Description, p.Location, p.CategoryId })
                .ToList();

            if (id != 0)
            {
                attractions = attractions.Where(a => a.CategoryId == id)
                    .ToList();
            }


            JObject attractionsJSON = new JObject(
                new JProperty("Attractions", new JArray(
                    from a in attractions
                    select new JObject(
                        new JProperty("id", a.AttractionId),
                        new JProperty("name", a.Name),
                        new JProperty("location", a.Location),
                        new JProperty("description", a.Description)
                        ))));

            data = attractionsJSON.ToString();

        }
        return data;
    }
```

**Serverside - Update 1**

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void GetLocations(int id, string type)
    {
        string data = "";


        if (type == "attraction")
        {
            var attractions = db.Attraction
                                .Where(a => a.AttractionId == id)
                                .Select(p => new { p.AttractionId, p.Name, p.Description, p.Location })
                                .ToList();


            JArray attractionsJSON = new JArray(
                    from a in attractions
                    select new JObject(
                        new JProperty("id", a.AttractionId),
                        new JProperty("name", a.Name),
                        new JProperty("location", a.Location),
                        new JProperty("description", a.Description)
                        ));

            data = attractionsJSON.ToString();
        }
        else if (type == "category")
        {
            var attractions = db.Attraction

                .Select(p => new { p.AttractionId, p.Name, p.Description, p.Location, p.CategoryId })
                .ToList();

            if (id != 0)
            {
                attractions = attractions.Where(a => a.CategoryId == id)
                    .ToList();
            }


            JArray attractionsJSON = new JArray(
                    from a in attractions
                    select new JObject(
                        new JProperty("id", a.AttractionId),
                        new JProperty("name", a.Name),
                        new JProperty("location", a.Location),
                        new JProperty("description", a.Description)
                        ));

            data = attractionsJSON.ToString();

        }


        var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(js.Serialize(data));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `dataType` parameter from the ajax call. From the [same blog](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/), see "dataType: none of your business"

Comment: @DanielJ.G. Unfortunately, even without it, I'm still receiving .d

Comment: Why do I get a "This site contains malware" warning when I click on the first link in this post?

Comment: @Mike It must have something to do with some malicious scripts that were recognized by Google as dangerous. Hopefully, the owner of the site will fix those.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try using void method with no return. instead write the output to response yourself!

```
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void GetLocations(int id, string type)
    {
     // var attractions = something ;

     var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(  js.Serialize(attractions )  );
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
   }
```

Very important to keep these 2 calls at end:

flush : makes sure output is written to stream

End : ends the stream to prevent asp.Net from writing empty Json to stream

Comment: I thought that was the answer and it seems like we're on a good path but this doesn't solve my problem. Actually, what I get is invalid JSON. JSON output can be seen here http://pastebin.com/NTWDfxtA

Comment: how do you create the json, with System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ?

Comment: Yes, I took your exact example and it removes the .d as expected but with invalid JSON.

Comment: by the way"data" var  in my example is the object not a string

Comment: yes the problem was using the string, while you need to pass the object to  Serialize()

Comment: Strange, this is what I get when I use object instead of string: [[[[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]]]]]. When I set data = attractionsJSON.ToString(); I receive invalid code and when I set data = attractionsJSON; I get above mentioned brackets.

Comment: Just pass attractions to Serialize(), I don't see need for Jobject, jArray

Comment: Whenever you visit Croatia let me know, I owe you a beer! :) Thank you, passing attractions directly to the object is the solution.