# AJAX Return object contains d in asp.net web form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hey guys Its a simple question but want to stop ajax return object contains `d`.

I asp.net web form

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myurl,
        data: JSON.stringify({value:"1"}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            //alert("i am in success");
            console.log(result);

        },
        failure: function (response) {
            console.log("I am in failure");
        }
    });
```

and
   in .cs file

```
        [WebMethod]

        public static string getSpareParts(string value)
        {
            List<data> spareParts;
            using (var db = new WaltonCrmEntities())
            {
                spareParts = db.SpareParts.Select(x => new data
                {
                    id = x.ItemID,
                    text = x.ItemName
                }).ToList();
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return js.Serialize(spareParts);
            //return spareParts;

        }
```

when result is return it will contain result in `result.d` but i want to stop this `d` thing .Simply result should be the `result`. Can anybody solve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830112/what-does-d-in-json-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not much you could do about this. That's the way ASP.NET WebMethods always serialize the response. The reason why Microsoft decided to wrap the response in this `.d` property is to protect against this particular [`JSON hijacking vulnerability`](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/). Of course you could always check in your `success` callback whether this property is present or not:

```
success: function (result) {
    var data = result.hasOwnProperty('d') ? result.d : result;
    console.log(data);
}
```

Also I would very strongly recommend against writing plumbing code in your WebMethod (like serialization stuff) and just return the proper object and let the infrastructure care about serialization:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<data> getSpareParts(string value)
{
    using (var db = new WaltonCrmEntities())
    {
        return db.SpareParts.Select(x => new data
        {
            id = x.ItemID,
            text = x.ItemName
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Now inside your success callback you can directly work with this collection without the need to additionally `JSON.parse` it:

```
success: function (result) {
    var data = result.hasOwnProperty('d') ? result.d : result;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log('id: ' + data[i].id + ', text: ' + data[i].text);
    }
}
```